# How to convert a column containing string "1yr 11mon" into number of months in python?

Tags: python, regex

I want to convert a column containing years and months data with string "1yr 11mon" into total number of months.

I guess i should do regex and remove whitespaces & characters and then write a function to convert year and months to total number of months but as i am new to programming in python i am not able to.

I expect the output of "1yr 11mon" to be 23 (i.e. 1 yr 11mon= 12 months + 11 months)

Comment: Could you post the code you are struggling with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the structure of the strings is the same in all cases, you could use [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to find both the year and month digits. Then simply multiply the years by `12` and add the months:

```
import re
s = "1yr 11mon"

r = re.findall('\d+', s)
int(r[0])*12 + int(r[1])
# 23
```

---

**Update**

To do so in a vectorized way for an entire dataframe column:

```
# example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':["1yr 11mon", "2yr 4mon"]})

     dates
0  1yr 11mon
1   2yr 4mon

df_ = df.dates.str.extractall('(\d+)').unstack()
df_.columns = df_.columns.droplevel(0)
df_.iloc[:,0].astype(int).mul(12) + df_.iloc[:,1].astype(int)
```

Which will output:

```
0    23
1    28
dtype: int64
```